# Trouble installing nodejs in pacman

Tags: javascript, node.js, manjaro, pacman

I have trouble installing nodejs  under Manjaro
The system told me "checking for inter-conflict".I got the message "Failed to commit transaction--
Failure to retrieve files"
Does this have something to do w dependemncies.

Thank you,

Much appreciated,

Xeperu

I don't know what to do

Comment: I suggest you use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm instead of installing from Pacman